# Sort a custom dictionary by commentDate

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary

This is my data in Firestore:

[image]

My comment model:

```
class CommentModel {

var commentText: String?
var commentDate: NSObject?
var uid: String?
var username : String?
var profileImageUrl: String?

init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    commentText = dictionary["commentText"] as? String
    commentDate = dictionary["commentDate"] as? NSObject
    uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String
    username = dictionary["username"] as? String
    profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String
    }
}
```

My comments dictionary contains all documents of "comments".

XCode gives me the following suggestion, but I am unsure how to use it.

```
self.comments.sorted { (CommentModel, CommentModel) -> Bool in

                }
```

How can I sort my dictionary by the commentDate?

Comment: Store the date as a `Date`. Not as an `NSObject?`.

Comment: `NSObject` is a very generic type be specific on types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
self.comments.sort { $0.commentDate  < $1.commentDate  }
```

make sure `comments` is declared as `var` , also cast it as a `Date` or `String`

```
commentDate = dictionary["commentDate"] as? Date
```

OR

```
commentDate = dictionary["commentDate"] as? String
```

Comment: Hi Sh_Khan, I tried this already and got this - Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '[CommentModel]'

Comment: the sort has no return its mutating